# Getting linker error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyInit_your_module_name when building a Python extension using Pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I'm trying to build a Python extension using Pybind11, and I believe I set up all libs, linker related objects correctly. However I get this weird linker error!
This is my example input

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <torch/script.h>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
namespace py = pybind11;

#include <FV/FV.h>
//template <class T>
class PyManager 
{
public:
    PyManager(std::string model_path, std::string img_bank_folder_root, std::string cache_folder,
        std::string pnet, std::string rnet, std::string onet, bool rebuildCache)
    {
        auto config = FV::Load_Default_Settings();
        //...
        fv = std::make_shared<FV>(config);
    }


    int AddUser(std::string user_id, std::string img_fldr_path)
    {
        return fv->AddNewUser(user_id, img_fldr_path);
    }
    int RemoveUser(std::string user_id)
    {
        return fv->RemoveUser(user_id);
    }
    int UpdateUser(std::string user_id, std::string new_images_folder_path)
    {
        return fv->UpdateUser(user_id, new_images_folder_path);
    }
    int UpdateUsersInBulk(std::vector<std::string> userIDs, std::string ID_folders_path, bool is_delete_granted = true, bool show_dbg_info = true)
    {
        return fv->UpdateUsersInBulk(userIDs, ID_folders_path, is_delete_granted, show_dbg_info);

    }
    int RenameId(std::string old_id, std::string new_id)
    {
       return fv->RenameUserID(old_id, new_id);
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<FV> fv;
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(PythonUserManager, m) {
    py::class_<PyManager>(m, "Manager")
        .def(py::init<std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, bool>())
        .def("add", &PyManager::AddUser)
        .def("remove", &PyManager::RemoveUser)
        .def("update", &PyManager::UpdateUser)
        .def("rename", &PyManager::RenameId)
        .def("update_in_bulk", &PyManager::UpdateUsersInBulk);
}
```

and this is how I'm building the extension (`setup.py`):

```py
import os, sys
from os import environ, getcwd
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from distutils import sysconfig
import getpass 
cpp_args = ['/std:c++17']

user = getpass.getuser()
sfc_module = Extension(
    'PythonManager_Pybind11', sources=['PythonManager_Pybind11.cpp', 'D:/cpp/port/LibtorchPort/Dependencies/include/messages/Config.pb.cc'],

    include_dirs=['pybind11/include',
                  f'C:/Users/{user}/Anaconda3/include',
                  f'C:/Users/{user}/Anaconda3/include/pybind11/',
                  "D:/External Libs/Opencv3.4.10_vc14_vc15/opencv3.4/include",
                  "D:/cpp/port/LibtorchPort/Dependencies/include",
                  "D:/cpp/port/LibtorchPort/Dependencies/libtorch-release-latest/libtorch/include",
                  "D:/cpp/port/LibtorchPort/Dependencies/libtorch-release-latest/libtorch/include/torch/csrc/api/include",
                  f'C:/Users/{user}/Anaconda3/Library/include',
                  f'C:/Users/{user}/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include'],

    library_dirs=[# python3.6.7: f'C:/Users/{user}/Anaconda3/pkgs/openblas-0.3.3-h535eed3_1001/Library/lib',
                  "D:/cpp/port/LibtorchPort/x64/Release",
                  "D:/External Libs/Opencv3.4.10_vc14_vc15/opencv3.4/x64/vc14/lib",
                  "D:/cpp/port/LibtorchPort/Dependencies/libtorch-release-latest/libtorch/lib",
                  f'C:/Users/{user}/Anaconda3/libs',
                  f'C:/Users/{user}/Anaconda3'],

    libraries=['FV', 'libprotobuf-lite','libprotobuf','libprotoc','c10','asmjit','clog','cpuinfo','dnnl','fbgemm','mkldnn','torch','torch_cpu'],
    language='c++',
    extra_compile_args=cpp_args,
    )

setup(
    name='UserManager',
    version='1.0',
    description='Python package with PythonExtension C++ extension (PyBind11)',
    ext_modules=[sfc_module],
)
```

results in the following linker error :

```
    creating C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-xl1k7s1f\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:D:/Codes/fac_ver/cpp/port/LibtorchPort/x64/Release "/LIBPATH:D:/External Libs/Opencv3.4.10_vc14_vc15/opencv3.4/x64/vc14/lib" /LIBPATH:D:/Codes/fac_ver/cpp/port/LibtorchPort/Dependencies/libtorch-release-latest/libtorch/lib /LIBPATH:C:/Users/User/Anaconda3/libs /LIBPATH:C:/Users/User/Anaconda3 /LIBPATH:C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\ATLMFC\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" FV.lib libprotobuf-lite.lib libprotobuf.lib libprotoc.lib c10.lib asmjit.lib clog.lib cpuinfo.lib dnnl.lib fbgemm.lib mkldnn.lib torch.lib torch_cpu.lib /EXPORT:PyInit_PythonManager_Pybind11 build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\PythonManager_Pybind11.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\Codes/fac_ver/cpp/port/LibtorchPort/Dependencies/include/messages/Config.pb.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\PythonManager_Pybind11.cp37-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\PythonManager_Pybind11.cp37-win_amd64.lib
    LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyInit_PythonManager_Pybind11
    build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\PythonManager_Pybind11.cp37-win_amd64.lib : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Enterprise\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.27.29110\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I made a silly mistake! it seems when defining the `PYBIND11_MODULE`, the first name, and the name used in `setup()` need to be the same as the source file, i.e. `PythonManager_Pybind11.cpp` in my case. This why the linker was complaining about the actual object which was the main source file.
Making these changes, now everything builds just fine.

This is how it looks after these minor changes:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <torch/script.h>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
namespace py = pybind11;

#include <FV/FV.h>
//template <class T>
class PyManager 
{
public:
    PyManager(std::string model_path, std::string img_bank_folder_root, std::string cache_folder,
        std::string pnet, std::string rnet, std::string onet, bool rebuildCache)
    {
        auto config = FV::Load_Default_Settings();
        //...
        fv = std::make_shared<FV>(config);
    }


    int AddUser(std::string user_id, std::string img_fldr_path)
    {
        return fv->AddNewUser(user_id, img_fldr_path);
    }
    int RemoveUser(std::string user_id)
    {
        return fv->RemoveUser(user_id);
    }
    int UpdateUser(std::string user_id, std::string new_images_folder_path)
    {
        return fv->UpdateUser(user_id, new_images_folder_path);
    }
    int UpdateUsersInBulk(std::vector<std::string> userIDs, std::string ID_folders_path, bool is_delete_granted = true, bool show_dbg_info = true)
    {
        return fv->UpdateUsersInBulk(userIDs, ID_folders_path, is_delete_granted, show_dbg_info);

    }
    int RenameId(std::string old_id, std::string new_id)
    {
       return fv->RenameUserID(old_id, new_id);
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<FV> fv;
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(PythonManager_Pybind11, m) {
    py::class_<PyManager>(m, "Manager")
        .def(py::init<std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, std::string, bool>())
        .def("add", &PyManager::AddUser)
        .def("remove", &PyManager::RemoveUser)
        .def("update", &PyManager::UpdateUser)
        .def("rename", &PyManager::RenameId)
        .def("update_in_bulk", &PyManager::UpdateUsersInBulk);
}
```

and this is how I'm building the extension (`setup.py`):

```py
import os, sys
from os import environ, getcwd
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from distutils import sysconfig
import getpass 
cpp_args = ['/std:c++17']

user = getpass.getuser()
sfc_module = Extension(
    'PythonManager_Pybind11', sources=['PythonManager_Pybind11.cpp', 'D:/cpp/port/LibtorchPort/Dependencies/include/messages/Config.pb.cc'],

    include_dirs=['pybind11/include',
                  f'C:/Users/{user}/Anaconda3/include',
                  f'C:/Users/{user}/Anaconda3/include/pybind11/',
                  "D:/External Libs/Opencv3.4.10_vc14_vc15/opencv3.4/include",
                  "D:/cpp/port/LibtorchPort/Dependencies/include",
                  "D:/cpp/port/LibtorchPort/Dependencies/libtorch-release-latest/libtorch/include",
                  "D:/cpp/port/LibtorchPort/Dependencies/libtorch-release-latest/libtorch/include/torch/csrc/api/include",
                  f'C:/Users/{user}/Anaconda3/Library/include',
                  f'C:/Users/{user}/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include'],

    library_dirs=[# python3.6.7: f'C:/Users/{user}/Anaconda3/pkgs/openblas-0.3.3-h535eed3_1001/Library/lib',
                  "D:/cpp/port/LibtorchPort/x64/Release",
                  "D:/External Libs/Opencv3.4.10_vc14_vc15/opencv3.4/x64/vc14/lib",
                  "D:/cpp/port/LibtorchPort/Dependencies/libtorch-release-latest/libtorch/lib",
                  f'C:/Users/{user}/Anaconda3/libs',
                  f'C:/Users/{user}/Anaconda3'],

    libraries=['FV', 'libprotobuf-lite','libprotobuf','libprotoc','c10','asmjit','clog','cpuinfo','dnnl','fbgemm','mkldnn','torch','torch_cpu'],
    language='c++',
    extra_compile_args=cpp_args,
    )

setup(
    name='PythonManager_Pybind11',
    version='1.0',
    description='Python package with PythonExtension C++ extension (PyBind11)',
    ext_modules=[sfc_module],
)
```

Now doing a :
`pip wheel .` or `pip install -e .` builds the extension just fine.